# PTIJ: Why does every daf in Gemara say "pork"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If you look at every *daf* (page) of Gemara (on the standard Vilna edition), it says "pork", followed by a number.

Ex.
[image: pork page]
<sub>Source:[Mercava](https://themercava.com/app/books/metanav/8769)</sub>

Can the Gemara really be telling us that pork is okay, to the extent that sometimes it says you can have [24](https://themercava.com/app/books/metanav/3383)?

Why do we have written on top of every page a food that is prohibited in the [Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.7)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 12):

This isn't telling us that you should eat *pig* (chazir), rather it is reminding us to always *chazer* (review) what we learn.

Answer (score 10):

It’s actually a English word “park” meaning to stay on that specific page and don’t get up until you know it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

פרק is actually an abreviation of *porcupine*, which in Hebrew is דרבן. Now this word has many meanings. The word can mean to *spur*, meaning you should be michazek yourself. It can also mean *prick* to remind yourself to always do teshuva.
The word דרבן is also short for דרבנן. That is to teach you to always revere the rabbis and not to make light of their words.
As we see, even in one word there are so many hidden messages the rabbis are teaching us.